# Empty folders in WinMerge compare?

Tags: winmerge

[image]

Is there any way to filter these via the command line so they don't show up. The only thing I've found is that you can hide an item one by one but that's impractical with many folders. There's nothing under these file wise, it just shows as "Folders are different".

Answer (score 0):

Not my answer, but i think what you need is the accepted answer for  [WinMerge and Diffmerge](https://superuser.com/questions/300474/winmerge-and-diffmerge)